# Can't inflate the menu

Tags: android, android-menu

I am going to `inflate` a menu in my first `Activity`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The R.menu.main:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_serach"
    android:title="Search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

It doesn't work, but it inflates the another XML file named `R.menu.menu_home`.
The R.menu.menu_home:

```
<menu 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
android:id="@+id/action_star"
android:title="Search"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_half"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
     />
</menu>
```

But in my second `Activity`, it works, whether it's `R.menu.main` or  `R.menu.menu_home`.
  why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem.It's because i  replace the framelayout with a fragment in the activity and the onCreateOptionsMenu() method is in the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have to Override the class method, so add `@Override` before.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) you can get more info about the Override annotation.

Comment: And what if you change the name of the menu, or if you create a new xml menu file with the same contents?

Comment: When i change the name of the menu or create a new xml menu file with the same contents,it remain inflates the preview XML file .

Answer (score -2):

Use this code.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
 }
```